Theoretically, in low-conflict scenarios , can MySQL support tens of thousands of concurrent connections without a performance collapse?
In the process of optimizing MySQL, we discovered a performance collapse at 10,000 concurrent connections during benchmarksql testing. Is there a theoretical limitation, or is it an issue with MySQL's internal mechanisms?
Seeking a deeper underlying cause.

Which MySQL version? What benchmark? Was it still a low conflict at 10K connections? What sort of collapse? Did you measure with perf record -g and with debuginfo symbols installed identify the hot code paths?

In a BenchmarkSQL TPC-C standard test with 1,000 warehouses and minimal conflict, tools like perf may not reveal specific issues and only generally indicate latch contention

10K _active_connections are likely to over-saturate the network connectivity.  Is this 10K connections sitting idle?  Or 10K queries running simultaneously.?

In mainstream network environments, even with 10,000 concurrent connections, MySQL often struggles to saturate the network during TPC-C tests due to concurrency control limiting throughput.

The effective limit for one MySQL Server 8.0 seems to be about 512 concurrent connections under normal operation.
With the thread pool plugin, it can handle many more connections, provided they can share. This means low query traffic, so most connections are idle most of the time. If you're trying to drive thousands of running threads concurrently, the thread pool plugin won't help as much.
Read https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/the-new-mysql-thread-pool/
Of course, many other factors will affect the limit, including the types of queries, the server and storage capacity, resource contention, other processes on the same server, etc.

The new MySQL thread pool is a good choice for controlling a large number of concurrent connections to the transaction system.

I found a similar answer here: https://github.com/orgs/advancedmysql/discussions/7 . Thanks
